# How to load google recaptcha dynamically based on language?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, recaptcha

I have an application where one of four languages (English,French,Dutch,español) needs to be selected in form. 
The google reCaptcha comes below it.

I want to make it load dynamically on base of language selected. The recaptcha is based on script tag to which language should be passed

```
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit&hl=en" async defer></script>
```

All I need to do is just to change the last argument of script `(hl=en)` based on input and load the script dynamically. But i can't understand how to make it work.

Also the script should load again if the language is changed in dropdown above.

Is this any way possible for this to make work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grecaptcha.render()` and pass in the language to change it to your liking.
Note that you have to remove the previous captcha element before calling `render`.

```
// your desired language
let captchaLang = 'de';
let captchaSiteKey = '...';
let captchaElemId = 'container';

let captchaCallback = (e) => {
  document.querySelector('#' + captchaElemId).remove();     
  // deal with success
  // ...
};

// create new elem based on old one, keeps the styling
// you could also just use document.createElement()
let old = document.querySelector('#' + captchaElemId);
let clone = old.cloneNode(false);
old.replaceWith(clone);

// render captcha with new language
grecaptcha.render(captchaElemId, {
  sitekey: captchaSiteKey,
  callback: captchaCallback,
  hl: captchaLang
});
```